# How to stop/start Azure Function from PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

Is there a way how stop (and then start again) Azure Function from PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Start-AzureRmWebApp**

```html
Start-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name "ContosoWebApp"
```

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/start-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0**

**Stop-AzureRmWebApp**

```html
PS C:\>Stop-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name "ContosoWebApp"
```

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/stop-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0**

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer on 1/23/20

We have released a Preview module to managed Azure Functions. This can be found at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions/0.0.1-preview.

Please give it a try and send us feedback at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues. When opening an issue, please make sure `[Az.Functions]` is included in the title.

To install the module, run the following command from the latest version of `psws` which can be downloaded at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases.

`Install-Module -Name Az.Functions -AllowPrerelease`

After installation, here is an example to stop a function app:

```bsh
# Here is how you can stop a function app:
# 1) Stop a function app by name and resource group
Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name <FuntionAppName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> 

# Stop a function app name using piping
Get-AzFunctionApp -Name <FuntionAppName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> | 
| Stop-AzFunctionApp
```

Cheers,

Francisco